# A submersion $f: S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S^2 = \{(x_1,x_2,x_3) \in \mathbb{R}^3: x_1^2 + x_2^2 + x_3^2 = 1\}$. Does there exist a submersion $f: S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$, namely a maps such that the tangent map $T_x f: T_x S^2 \rightarrow \mathbb{R}^2$ is everywhere surjective?

As I cannot seem to find a map whose jacobian has full rank I'm thinking that the answer is no but I'm having trouble proving this.

Comment: I remember that this usually is proved with some cohomologies.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Note that a submersion between two manifolds of equal dimension is a local diffeomorphism (since a linear map $\mathbb{F}^n \to \mathbb{F}^n$ is surjective iff it's injective, for any field $\mathbb{F}$ and any $n \in \mathbb{N}$).

Therefore, the map $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is an open map. Its image must therefore be an open set. The image must also be compact, hence closed and bounded. Therefore, the image is a nonempty clopen proper subset of $\mathbb{R}^2$. But this contradicts the fact that $\mathbb{R}^2$ is connected.

So there is no submersion $S^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

If the tangent map was everywhere surjective, then it would also be everywhere injective. Then, we could pull back the distinguished vector field in the $x$ direction to produce a non-vanishing vector field on the sphere. This would contradict the hairy ball theorem.